# modifying sparse matrix using advanced indexing in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matrix-indexing

I'm trying to use advanced indexing to modify a big sparse matrix. Say you have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

A = sp.lil_matrix((10, 10))
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

idx = [1,4]
A[idx, idx] += a
```

Why this code doesn't work? It gives me the error

```
ValueError: shape mismatch in assignment
```

Comment: With a dense array, the same operation has the same problem, though the error message is: `ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (2,) doesn't match the broadcast shape (2,2)`.  Are you trying to set a diagonal, or a square of values?

Comment: I was trying to set a sub-matrix of A with the values of a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `idx = [1,4]`, `A[idx, idx]` returns a sparse matrix of shape `(1,2)` with the elements `A[1,1]` and `A[4,4]`. However, `a` has shape `(2,2)`. Therefore, there is a mismatch in shape. If you want to assign `A[1,1]`, `A[1,4]`, `A[4,1]` and `A[4,4]` to `a`, you should do:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

A = sp.lil_matrix((10, 10))
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

idx = np.array([1,4])
A[idx[:, np.newaxis], idx] += a  # use broadcasting
```